# Need some quick C# regex help

Tags: c#, regex

I have this html:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/">This is the content.</a>
```

I just need to get rid of the anchor tag html around the content text, so that all I end up with is "This is the content".

Can I do this using Regex.Replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex: `<a[^>]+?>(.*?)</a>`

Check this Regex with the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)-class and iterate through the result collection
and you should get your inner text.

```
String text = "<a href=\"link.php\">test</a>";

Regex rx = new Regex("<a[^>]+?>(.*?)</a>");
// Find matches.
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

// Report the number of matches found.
Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found. \n", matches.Count);

// Report on each match.
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("Groups:");
    foreach (var g in match.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
  1 matches found. 
  <a href=\"link.php\">test</a> 
  Groups:
  <a href=\"link.php\">test</a> 
  test
```

The match expression in `()` is stored in the second item of `match`'s `Groups` collection (the first item is the whole match itself). Each expression in `()` gets into the `Groups` collection. See the MSDN for further information.

Comment: You can also replace using the group by index instead of iterating through all results, e.g. Regex.Replace(yourHtml, "<a[^>]+?>(.*?)</a>", "$1"); would return the inner text.

Answer (score 0):

If you had to use Replace, this'd work for simple string content inside the tag:

```
Regex r = new Regex("<[^>]+>");
string result = r.Replace(@"<a href=""http://www.site.com/"">This is the content.</a>", "");
Console.WriteLine("Result = \"{0}\"", result);
```

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You could also use groups in Regex.

For example, the following would give you the content of any tag.

```
      Regex r = new Regex(@"<a.*>(.*)</a>"); 
      // Regex r = new Regex(@"<.*>(.*)</.*>"); or any kind of tag

        var m = r.Match(@"<a href=""http://www.site.com/"">This is the content.</a>");

        string content = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

you use groups in regexes by using the parenthesis, although group 0 is the whole match, not just the group.

Comment: Your regex won't work in every case. For example if you have <a>test1</a><a>test2</a>... you will get always test2

Comment: Yeah but thats not like the example he used, he made it seem like he is only gonna process 1 un-nested tag at a time